# File Folder error when using camera

Tags: xamarin.android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I have followed this [docs](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) in implementing in taking a photo and picking a photo in Xamarin. I was able to implement and worked in picking a photo but I have error in using the function TakePhotoAsync() which is used to open the camera to take picture. I have googling for possible solutions but nothing works for me. I did not modify any permission or add from the current which work on Picking a photo.

It crashes in this line:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
            });
```

I am testing in the emulator: AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus(Android 6.0 - API 23)

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file. Please check documentation on how to set this up in your project.
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I did solve the error by downgrading the version of the plugin to Xam.Plugin.Media 3.1.2 from Xam.Plugin.Media 3.1.3. I didn't change anything in my codes.